# "$\omega \times 2$ is not order isomorphic to any ordinal number" in the inner model $V_{\omega \cdot 2}$

Tags: logic, set-theory

I have a problem in my course on inner models of set theory which I can't approach:

> Let $V_{\omega \cdot 2}$ be a set in the von Neumann hierarchy of sets and $\omega \times 2$ be a direct product of ordinals with lexicographical order. Show that $V_{\omega \cdot 2}$ is an inner model of the following statement: "$\omega \times 2$ is not order isomorphic to any ordinal number".

Where should I start? Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: The ordinals of this model are the ordinals strictly less than $\omega \cdot 2$, whereas the order type of the well-ordered set in question is $\omega\cdot 2.$ Making this into a rigorous proof involves invoking absoluteness for transitive models in a couple ways. (On a side note, this isn’t the usual use of the terminology “inner” model.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oh, so terminology-wise, is it better to say "the relativization of the statement holds for set/class $M$"?

Comment: Just “the set is a model of the statement” would be standard (which means exactly that the relativization of the statement holds in the set). What I was referring to is that usually the term *inner* model means a proper class that contains all the ordinals (and satisfies the relativizations of the axioms of interest). But that’s not a big deal and won’t impede anyone’s understanding of the question.

Comment: Who is teaching this course? Normally the term "inner model" is reserved for transitive class models that contain all the ordinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess this is the issue with my translation from Russian terminology. I have already spotted that litteral translation does not work well while we are talking about models of set theory.